# Why emacs Tuareg mode shows different color for functions in Ocaml?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

Just want to know why `Tuareg mode` shows different colour for functions?

for example, as shown below, function `create_percolation` and `index_of` show `blue` color and `is_open` is in brown color.

**Why??**

[image]

Comment: It is simply a bug of Tuareg. If the first arg of function is a record, Tuareg fails to recognize it as a function definition. Tuareg is written in emacs lisp and itself knows nothing about OCaml syntax tree like OCaml compiler does. So you should not expect something perfect from it. If you do not like it, how about submit a bug report to tuareg mode development website?

Comment: @camlspotter Maybe you can write your comments as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply a bug of Tuareg. If the first arg of function is a record, Tuareg fails to recognize it as a function definition. Tuareg is written in emacs lisp and itself knows nothing about OCaml syntax tree like OCaml compiler does. So you should not expect something perfect from it. If you do not like it, how about submit a bug report to tuareg mode development website?